# How to remove a comma 2nd to the last line of the file using SED?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to search and remove a comma `,` at the 2nd to the last line using sed.

This is what I have now:

```
}
   "user-account-id": "John",
   "user-account-number": "v1001",
   "user-account-app": "v10.0.0",
   "user-account-dbase": "v10.1.0",
}
```

I want the end result to be like this:

```
}
   "user-account-id": "John",
   "user-account-number": "v1001",
   "user-account-app": "v10.0.0",
   "user-account-dbase": "v10.1.0"
}
```

I thought I found the answer an hour after I posted this but I was wrong. It didn't work.

Dry run with any of these combination doesn't work:

```
sed '2,$ s/,$//' filename
sed '2,$ s/,//' filename
sed '2,$ s/,//g' filename
sed '2,$s/,$//' filename
sed '2,$s/,//' filename
sed '2,$s/,//g' filename
```

Actual removal with any of these combination doesn't work:

```
sed -i '2,$ s/,$//' filename
sed -i '2,$ s/,//' filename
sed -i '2,$ s/,//g' filename
sed -i '2,$s/,$//' filename
sed -i '2,$s/,//' filename
sed -i '2,$s/,//g' filename
```

I thought running `sed` with `'2,$` would only modify "2nd to the last line" in the file.

The output would just delete commas in every line, which doesn't make sense:

```
}
   "user-account-id": "John"
   "user-account-number": "v1001"
   "user-account-app": "v10.0.0"
   "user-account-dbase": "v10.1.0"
}
```

Comment: That looks like JSON, in which case fixing whatever is producing invalid JSON with a trailing comma is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2,$` is a *range* starting at the 2nd line from the beginning and ending at the last line (so all lines except for the first one). Modifying the 2nd last line is hard in `sed`, see for example [Replace the "pattern" on second-to-last line of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38649053/6770384).

But in your case, there is an easier solution with GNU `sed`:

Treat the entire file as one string and delete the last comma followed by an `}` at the end of the file (ignoring any whitespace, even linebreaks).

```
sed -Ez 's/,([ \t\r\n]*)\}([ \t\r\n]*)$/\1}\2/' file
```

In case you know the last

Comment: This command works! Thanks Socowi! You're the man!

Answer (score 1):

Another tactic: reverse the file, remove the trailing comma on the *first* time it's seen, then re-reverse the file:

```bash
tac file  | awk -v p=1 'p && /,$/ {sub(/,$/, ""); p=0} 1' | tac
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;$s/,//;P;D' file
```

Open a two line window throughout the file and when the last line is encountered, remove the first `,`.